# Need to select Excel cell value based on chosen row and column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a reference table in excel, as per the below diagram in a worksheet.

[image]

And I have another worksheet, where user can select **Complexity** from drop down list (which is a look up of column B in previous diagram), and **Category** (which is a look up of row 3 in previous diagram).

[image]

What I need is - the Column titled "Coding" to pick up the cell value from the Diagram 1 based on the value chosen in **Categories** and **Complexity** Drop down.

For example, in Row 1 of 2nd diagram, the Required value is: **24**

How can I achieve this? Can it be done using excel formulas?

Comment: This is a standard 2-way look up. You can easily do it using `MATCH` and `INDEX`. e.g. https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match but I'm sure you'll find hundreds of links online if you search for 2-way look up in Excel. But basically it will be `=INDEX(Effort!C4:H8,MATCH(complexity,Effort!B4:B8,0),MATCH(category,Effort!C4:H4,0))`

Comment: Thank you Dan, I did not know this is called Two way lookup. Could you please copy your comment as an answer so that I can Mark it accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard 2-way look up. You can easily do it using MATCH and INDEX. e.g. exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match but I'm sure you'll find hundreds of links online if you search for 2-way look up in Excel. But basically it will be

```
=INDEX(Effort!C4:H8,MATCH(complexity,Effort!B4:B8,0),MATCH(c‌​ategory,Effort!C4:H4‌​,0))
```

where `complexity` is the cell containing your desired complexity, `category` is the cell containing your desired `category` and `Effort` is the name of the worksheet with that first table your depicted.